# Why am i getting this ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x

now this is the source. Someone please help me how to deal with this

```
for k in range(no_of_resc):
                name_resch = input('enter then name of the patient you want to reschedule : ')
                date_resc = input('enter the date you want to reschedule : ')
                date_for_resc = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_resc, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s')
                print('the appointment is rescheduled for ',name_resch,'and on',date_for_resc)
                resch_pat.append(name_resch)
            print('the appointment is rescheduled for :' , resch_pat)
```

now now this is the output So here i have 6options (forget about those option) when i enter the date i want to get appointment im getting this error something like ValueError

```
1 . register no.of  doctors 
2 . register no.of patients 
3 . do you want to book appointments ? 
4 . reschedule the appointments ?      
5 . cancel the appointments. 
6 . Exit 
enter your selection : 3 
enter the number of doc : 1 
enter number of patient : 1 
>> 
enter the name of the doctor : knan 
is the doctor free? (y/n) : y 
[]
['y ']
enter the name of the patient : ganesh 
['ganesh ']
lol
enter the date you want to get appointed (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm): 2023-10-9 8:31:31 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Desktop\vsc\JavaScript\05-Guess-My-Number\starter\doctor.py", line 51, in <module>
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(appnt_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime        
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\_strptime.py", line 352, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains: :31
```

Comment: You enter seconds in the date (`2023-10-9 8:31:31`), whereas the conversion (`%H:%M`) only include hours and minutes.

Comment: The line that throws the error is ``datetime.datetime.strptime(appnt_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')`` - and this line is not part of the code you've posted. please provide a [mcve]

Comment: your indentation appears to be broken (which - being python - is a serious issue when debugging code)

Comment: in which line can you say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line, you enter the date with seconds:

```
enter the date you want to get appointed (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm): 2023-10-9 8:31:31
```

But the conversion is not correct with this pattern, you have here (c:\Desktop\vsc\JavaScript\05-Guess-My-Number\starter\doctor.py):

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(appnt_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

The conversion should be:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(appnt_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s')
```